# bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied whenever I open a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 13.10, when I open a new terminal, I sometimes get the following output on the terminal:

```
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied
```

However, the permissions should be fine:

```
>ls -l /etc/bash.bashrc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2177 Mär 30  2013 /etc/bash.bashrc*
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it? What is the purpose of the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` and where exactly does it gets called?

Content of this file:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.

    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

Comment: What is the *contents* of your /etc/bash.bashrc.

Comment: I added the content- Not sure, where it comes from or why I get this error only recently.

Comment: I looked in to my permission and a couple of other machines an I see this `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8871 jul 11 04:52 /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: These permissions were my original ones as well. But because of the error I changed them as listed in the question, without success.

Comment: What are the permissions of the `/etc` directory ?

Answer (score 6):

Try: `chmod 0755 /etc` as root. You could have run into an issue with the /etc directory's permissions being wrong. Also revert the permissions of the bash.bashrc file to their original permissions `chmod 644 /etc/bash.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with the Samba AD user so I have deleted and recreated with the same user info. on the AD console. I have renamed only the home directory, `mv /home/domain/user /home/domain/user.ex`assumed that home directory alone might've affected and made the user logged in fresh then moved whole contents back to the new home directory from the renamed home directory. `mv /home/domain/user.ex/* home/domain/user`Therfore home directory restored to stock and `abrt-cli status' timed out`error disappeared as well.